# Eliminating a 3 way switch in a 3 gang outlet

Tags: electrical, smart-switch

I want to use some smart switches and wanted to eliminate the use of 3 way switch in a 3 gang outlet. Can you please walk me through which wires to connect and which ones to cap.

Switch 1 - three way switch which operates with another three way switch upstairs --> this is the one i want to eliminate. I may put the a smart switch at the junction at the top of the box if this is possible.

Switch 2 - single pole switch that controls main entrance light --> this is where I have a smart switch

Switch 3 - single pole switch that controls outside light --> this is where i have another smart switch

When i opened up the box - all the neutrals were packed together. I have split them up and connected them together for switch 2 and switch 3 to work (which it does).

I also noticed that one of the black wires ran through each of the switches originally. I have now separated them between the 2 smart switches and the 1 dumb switch.

Currently, the three way switch does not work.

My question is - can i have a 1 dumb three way switch with 2 smart switches. Also, can all the neutrals be connected together to complete the circuit?

I am open to replacing the three way switch to a single pole that is simply controlled from upstairs.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this illuminate a *stairway*? Will you be able to control the stairway light from top and bottom?

Comment: Yes - it does illuminate a stairway, but there is plenty of light and not really necessary. I don't mind if it is just controlled from one end using a dumb switch downstairs or a smart switch upstairs.

Comment: That's not your call, though.  A person needs to be able to light the stairway from either top or bottom.

Comment: Can you post pictures of what is  inside the two junction boxes? I.e. the wiring behind the switches and how it attaches to the switches. ..

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes please?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, if the switches are all on the same circuit (breaker), you tie all the neutrals together.
2. Yes, you can have dumb & smart switches in the same box. And receptacles. And all kinds of other things.
3. As Harper noted, you must have switches for stairway lighting at top & bottom. So if you want to put in a smart switch for one end, put in a smart switch **remote** for the other end.